# Magento show animated gif image for product

Tags: magento, caching, product, animated-gif

I want to show animated gif images for product .
Uploading gif image is posible but the same is not seen on frontend.
I saw the functionality due to cache in magento animated gif images is not seen.
How can I implement it ?
Check [this](http://www.inkfruit.com/guys/guys-tshirts/led-tshirts/) link for reference.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the link doesn't have any products. Did you get this to work?

Comment: @miles : http://www.itsourstudio.com/hungry-hound-591

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can implement it .
Though your caching functionality will not work for animated gif image.
**copy file from**

**path :** app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php
**to**

**path :** app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php
**(create folders if necessary)**
Find the line **public function getUrl()** and replace the function with:

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        $baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
        $file = ('gif' == strtolower(pathinfo($this->_baseFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) ? $this->_baseFile : $this->_newFile;
        $path = str_replace($baseDir . DS, "", $file);
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . str_replace(DS, '/', $path);
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This helps, but I have some issues with rezised images.